# select cell in print layout

Tags: mouseevent, reportviewer, reporting-services

I want in `Print Layout Mode` of my report, by clicking a `cell` in a Table *`(Tablix)`*, the border color for that `cell` changes, and by clicking another `cell`, its `border color` changes and the other one's border changes back.

Actually I want to show selected item in other words. 
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh , this is a little bit tricky but works.

you can use the Action options for each cell to call to the same report.

in a specific cell, right click > text box properties > Action. 
From here you have 2 options:
1. call the same report and use the parameters to pass the HEX color code.
2. call a copy of the report with the relevant colors already defined.

hope this will help you...